# PHP Form Not Connecting to Database

Tags: php, sql-server

I am working on building a form to update/change/manage links in the sidebar of a page.  All of the basic functionality works so far except the update function.  The form loads, and when I add some debugging code the variables all pass and the SQL query builds properly and executes when I put it in SQL Studio directly.

The problem is the update page doesn't connect to the database.  It's the same connection set up that pulls the data (which may be part of the problem?), so I don't understand why it doesn't connect.

Below is a generic version of the code.  In case it matters, getpromos.php if called also when the right side bar is loaded on the overall page to display the active promos.  There is also some basic java going on to toggle which promo is being displayed for editing on the admin page.

The page loads up a drop down menu of Promo Names, plus an option to add a new Promo.  Then displays the selected promo for editing.  Normally it will forward back to the edit page but I've commented that section out for troubleshooting.  I am not worried about validating the data or anything at this point, I am just working to get the update function working first.

adminrightbar.php

```
    <h4>Promo Manager</h4><br><br><hr><br>

<?php

include ('scripts/getpromos.php');
$promoselect=0;

echo "<div style=\"height:500px; margin-left:0; margin-right:auto;\">";
echo "<div style=\"height:75px; margin-left:0; margin-right:auto;\"><h1> Select which Promo you would like to edit.</h1> <br><select name=\"promomenu\" onchange=\"changepromo(value)\">";
echo "<option>Please Select a Promo</option>";
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))  {

  echo "<option value=\"".@$row['id']."\">".@$row['name']."</option>";

}
echo "<option value=\"99\">Add a New Promo</option>";
echo "</select></div>";
sqlsrv_close($thedb);


include ('scripts/getpromos.php');

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<div id=\"promodiv".@$row['id']."\" class=\"promoselectbox\"><h1>".$row['name']."</h1></br>";


    echo "<div style=\"float: left; width:600px; margin-left:0;  margin-top: 25px; margin-right:auto;\">";
    echo "<form action=\"scripts/updatepromos.php?id=".$row['id']."\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "Promo Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\" value=\"".@$row['name']."\"  style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Links to: <input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" id=\"url\" value=\"".@$row['url']."\" style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Image: <input type=\"text\" name=\"image\" id=\"image\" value=\"".@$row['image']."\" style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Text: <br><br><textarea type=\"text\" name=\"text\" id=\"text\" rows\"5\" cols=\"75\">".@$row['text']."</textarea><br><br>";
    echo "Enabled: <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"enable\" id=\"enable\" value=\"".@$row['enable']."\" ";
        if (@$row['enable'] == 1) { echo "checked"; }
    echo "><br><br>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit".@$row['id']."\" value=\"Update\">";
    echo "</form></div>";

    echo "<div style=\"width: 250px; float: right; margin-left:auto; margin-right:0; margin-top: 50px;\"><a href=\"".$row['url']."\"><img src=\"images/promo/".$row['image']."\"></a><br>".$row['text']."<br>";
    echo "</div></div>";
}

    echo "<div id=\"promodiv99\" class=\"promoselectbox\"><h1>Add New Promo</h1></br>";
    echo "<div style=\"float: left; width:600px; margin-left:0;  margin-top: 25px; margin-right:auto;\">";
    echo "<form action=\"scripts/updatepromos.php?id=99\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "Promo Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\"  style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Links to: <input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" id=\"url\"  style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Image: <input type=\"text\" name=\"image\" id=\"image\"  style=\"width: 300px;\"><br><br>";
    echo "Promo Text: <br><br><textarea type=\"text\" name=\"text\" id=\"text\" rows\"5\" cols=\"75\"></textarea><br><br>";
    echo "Enabled: <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"enable\" id=\"enable\"  ";
    echo "><br><br>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Update\">";
    echo "</form></div>";

    echo "<div style=\"width: 250px; float: right; margin-left:auto; margin-right:0; margin-top: 50px;\"><a href=\"".$row['url']."\"><img src=\"images/promo/".$row['image']."\"></a><br>".$row['text']."<br>";
    echo "</div></div>";

echo "</div>";
sqlsrv_close($thedb);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

function changepromo(select){
    $('.promoselectbox').hide();
    $('#promodiv'+select).show();
}
</script>
```

getpromos.php

```
<?php 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"userdb", "UID"=>$_SESSION['sqlsrvuser'], "PWD"=>$_SESSION['sqlsrvpass']);
$thedb = sqlsrv_connect( $_SESSION['sqldb'], $connectionInfo);
if ($thedb->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$results = sqlsrv_query ($thedb, "SELECT * FROM userdb.db ORDER BY ordering");

?>
```

updatepromos.php

```
<?php 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"userdb", "UID"=>$_SESSION['sqlsrvuser'], "PWD"=>$_SESSION['sqlsrvpass']);
$thedb = sqlsrv_connect( $_SESSION['sqldb'], $connectionInfo);
if( $thedb ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


echo "<br><br>Updating....";

if ($_GET['id'] == 99) {
    echo "Add a new Promo";
    }
else {
    $sql = "UPDATE thedb.db SET name='".$_POST['name']."', enable='".$_POST['enable']."' WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = sqlsrv_query($thedb, $sql);
    if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  }
    }

sqlsrv_close($thedb);
# header("Location: {$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]}");
?>
```

EDIT: Specific error that occurs.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )
```

Comment: Do you have `Connection established` when you made an update? Are sure, your page `updatepromos.php` is call?

Comment: Yes, when hitting the Update button, the update page gets called, this throws out whatever information the page has.  I've tested this by using versions of the page that do nothing but construct a query variable and echo it and versions that just say "Updating".  The problem seems to be that update promos can't establish a connection.

Comment: You need to be using prepared statements. It would be trivial to overwrite the contents of every record in your database.

Comment: @RamenJunkie The user use for the connection has the right to make an update? If you print the update query and execute it in Sql Server, is it working?

Comment: They should have permissions to update.  I've copied the specific error intot he original post.  I never get any of the other status messages in the code (ie echo "Updating...").  The error below seems to suggest that the database can't be found, based on searching for it.  Except the connection set up is directly copied from getpromos.php which runs at least 3 times successfully in the whole process.

If I replace updatepromos with:

$sql = "UPDATE thedb.db SET name='".$_POST['name']."', enable='".$_POST['enable']."' WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
    echo $sql;

It builds a proper stmnt

Comment: Is this for a personal project/homework or something that is going to end up in a production environment?

Comment: Eventually, it's for an inward facing production site.  That said, at the moment, I am not looking for how to make super secure/efficient code right now, I am trying to solve the problem of getting the DB to update.  This is like step X of Y.

Even in production usage is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

The pages all load within a little framework of pages, index, header, rightbar, etc.

The page called to do the update, does not, it loads independently, and rolls back to the previous page.  So it was not receiving the global variables with the database username and password.